# Is it possible to add Row() inside of Row() in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on the app and making a page that a user can put their information on the page. Currently, the UI is something like this.

[image]

Like "Nickname", "Location", "Occupation", I want to add white bubble-ish shape on each of both "age" and "gender" drop down, and the code is something like this.

[image]

I made a single Row(), and inside, I want to create two Container() in order to make the white bubble shape, like Nickname text field.
Since both "Age" and "Gender" are text, and each of them has a drop-down, I thought create 2 Row() will achieve what I want to do it, but all the Row() are disappeared like the picture.

This is the model of the Row()...

Row[   Container[  Row[Text(), Expanded()]  ], Container[  Row[Text(), Expanded()]  ]   ]

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, please??

Answer (score 0):

You can use suffixIcon inside Decoration in TextField to archive it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Containers to Expanded

```dart
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Age",
                      ),
                      Expanded(child: DropdownButton())
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Gender",
                      ),
                      Expanded(child: DropdownButton())
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```